# Why Spark LogisticRegressionModel type mismatch?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

See:

[image: call here]

[image: object function]

IDEA prompts error in picture 1:

> Type mismatch, expected: LogisticRegressionModel, actual: LogisticRegressionModel

prompt error in picture 2:

> Symbol predict is inaccessible from this place

why...

Comment: are you sure you have imported class from the correct package?

Comment: i import a wrong package, indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to recheck the import list in your file. It is possible that you have imported `LogisticRegressionModel` from some wrong package.

Recheck, because in the mllib there is `org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel` and `org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel` is avaliable.

Comment: thank you! i import the wrong package, just like you say